# jQuery Reel Plugin: using example code, and valid reel image

Tags: jquery

Does anyone on God's green earth know why this doesn't work?  I have taken example code straight from jQuery reel's examples (http://test.vostrel.net/jquery.reel/example/object-movie-non-animated-sprite/), and combined it with an image that someone else is already using successfully with jQuery reel.

I've tried every concievable set of additional options from the documentation with no success.  No matter what I do, it just doesn't work.  It renders, and spins, but its all jacked up.  I see four spas instead of one, and as it rotates, when it moves to the next row of slides, it does it all wrong.

Copy and paste into a file, all assets are absolute.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>360 View</title>
    <meta charset='utf-8' content='text/html' http-equiv='Content-type' />
    <script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
    <script src='http://test.vostrel.net/jquery.reel/jquery.reel.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <img src="http://www.calderaspas.com/sites/default/files/cantabria-loading_0.gif" width="690" height="545"
      id="image"
      class="reel"
      data-image="http://www.calderaspas.com/sites/default/files/cantabria-360-2.jpg"
      data-frames="72">
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define the footage:

```
<img src="http://www.calderaspas.com/sites/default/files/cantabria-loading_0.gif" width="690" height="545"
  id="image"
  class="reel"
  data-image="http://www.calderaspas.com/sites/default/files/cantabria-360-2.jpg"
  data-frames="72"
  data-footage="24">
```

Comment: The "footage" is needed, because unlike the example (which has 6x6 and can therefore rely on the default value of 6) the photo used in the stack overflow question is 24x3.  The documentation clearly states the default value for footage is 6.

Comment: Indeed, I just read that part. Figured it out by tinkering with it initially.

Comment: Do you think that using an atypical sprite with non-default footage would improve the clarity of that particular example?

Comment: I'd love to blame it on bad examples and documentation but it's just not the case. Honestly I just wasn't studying and observing the default values as much as I was reading the description of them.  

Some re-ordering might help, perhaps putting "footage" after "frames" so you read them back to back.  

I understand "rows" now, but at first, since I wasn't working with a sprite that was going to use multiple rows, I interpreted that as the number of rows in the sprite itself.  That was a dark path that could probably be clarified better.  

All in all though great plugin Petr.

Comment: @TylerKasten, Thank you for your feedback! I guess a terminology glossary is the next thing to go into the wiki :)